# Сортировка списка по одному из атрибутов класса, экземпляры которого содержатся в данном списке

Tags: python, python-3.x

У нас имеется список в котором содержаться экземпляры класса Книга:

```
class Book:
    def __init__(self, title, author, publisher, year, pages_quantity, price):
        self.title = title
        self.authors = author
        self.publisher = publisher
        self.year = year                        # publication's year
        self.pages_quantity = pages_quantity
        self.price = price


book1 = Book("Financier", "Dreiser", "LolKek", 2017, 608, 238)
book2 = Book("Atlas Shrugged", "Rand", "Azzbuka", 2015, 1078, 1504)
book3 = Book("The God Delusion", "Dawkins", "HelloWorld", 2016, 518, 499)
book4 = Book("War and Peace. Volume One", "Tolstoy", "HomelandPublisher", 1999, 1217, 904)

books = list()
books.append(book1)
books.append(book2)
books.append(book3)
books.append(book4)
```

Необходимо отсортировать элементы списка по авторам в каждом экземпляре в алфавитном порядке.
Думал, что можно с помощью метода sorted, однако не удалось.
В голову совсем не приходит, каким способом можно провернуть.

Не знаю за что зацепиться, буду рад подсказкам, заранее благодарю!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Book:
    def __init__(self, title, author, publisher, year, pages_quantity, price):
        self.title = title
        self.authors = author
        self.publisher = publisher
        self.year = year                        # publication's year
        self.pages_quantity = pages_quantity
        self.price = price


book1 = Book("Financier", "Dreiser", "LolKek", 2017, 608, 238)
book2 = Book("Atlas Shrugged", "Rand", "Azzbuka", 2015, 1078, 1504)
book3 = Book("The God Delusion", "Dawkins", "HelloWorld", 2016, 518, 499)
book4 = Book("War and Peace. Volume One", "Tolstoy", "HomelandPublisher", 1999, 1217, 904)

books = list()
books.append(book1)
books.append(book2)
books.append(book3)
books.append(book4)


for v in list(sorted(books, key=lambda x: x.authors)):
    print(v.authors) # Dawkins Dreiser Rand Tolstoy
```